Why is $RP \subseteq BPP$?
Lets define $P_M(x)$ as the probability that machine M accepts x.
Let $L \in RP$.
Then, if $x \notin L$, we get that $P_M(x)=0$, which is less than $\frac{1}{3}$, so all good here.
But if $x \in L$, we get $\frac{1}{2} \leq P_M(x)$, which doesn't imply $\frac{2}{3} \leq P_M(x)$.
So I assume we need to define some machine M' based on the given M, but I don't really know where to start.
This is part of an introductory course in computability, so I assume this has a simple proof

Searching for "RP contained in BPP" immediately turns up proofs of this.  I imagine it's likely found in many standard textbooks on randomized algorithms as well.  Our expectation on this site is that you do a substantial amount of research before asking.  Our goal is to build up an archive of knowledge that will help others in the future, but I don't see much point in repeating material that is already widely available in standard resources (textbooks, lecture notes, etc.)

@D.W. Though I mainly agree with you that OP could have searched a little better, I think that it is not a problem that textbook proofs are repeated on CS.SE: it just makes this website a reference for ANY CS question.

Repeat the algorithm twice, and tada! The probability of error becomes less than $\frac14\leqslant \frac13$.
